# Why is a wrong Method on a Controller in my Server being invoked by a Service?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, sequelize.js, vuejs3

I am working with Sequelize, SqLite and VueJs.
In my Service i try to invoke the "indexRadar" method of my Controller. But instead the "index" method is getting invoked.

In my .vue file when this line is executed

```
(await ProgrammService.indexRadar(this.activeRadars[i])).data
```

The console in the Browser logs:
indexRadar Service
Then the console in the server logs:
wrong destination

But 'just index Service' is never logged.

The ProgrammController.js:

```
const {Programm} = require('../models')
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

module.exports = {
    async index (req,res) {
        console.log('wrong destination')
    .
    .
    },
    async show (req,res) {
        .
    .
    .        
    },
    async post (req,res) {
        .
    .
    . 
    },
    async put (req,res) {
        .
    .
    . 
    },
    async indexRadar (req,res) {
        console.log('right destination')
        .
    .
    . 
    }
}
```

routes.js:

```
    .
    .
const ProgrammController = require('./controllers/ProgrammController')
        .
    .


module.exports = (app) => {
        .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

    app.get('/programms',
    ProgrammController.index)

    app.get('/programms',
    ProgrammController.indexRadar)

    app.post('/programms',
    ProgrammController.post)

    app.get('/programms/:programmId',
    ProgrammController.show)

    app.put('/programms/:programmId',
    ProgrammController.put)
    
        .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

}
```

ProgrammService.js:

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
    index (search, indexList) {
        console.log('just index Service')
        return Api().get('programms', {
            params: {
                search: search,
                indexList: indexList
            }
        })
    },
    post (programm) {
        return Api().post('programms', programm)
    },
    show (programmId) {
        return Api().get(`programms/${programmId}`)
    },
    put (programm) {
        return Api().put(`programms/${programm.id}`, programm)
    },
    indexRadar (radar) {
        console.log('indexRadar Service')
        return Api().get('programms', {
            params: {
                radar: radar
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is my first project with Js, Sequelize, Vue and SqLite so i am completely lost.

Comment: You have identical routes for `index` and `indexRadar`. it executes the first one.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was sufficient to have the different names in methods. But how do I change that? Essentially I want to do a get on /programms.

Comment: You can rename one of the route. for example: `app.get('/programms/index', ProgrammController.index)`, and let the `programms` route to the desired controller method. Don't forget to rename the route also in API service for `index`: `Api().get('programms/index', ...)